# How to capture MQTT data locally in SSH remote server using Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, remote-server, tcpdump

I want to capture MQTT packets on the SSH Linux-based remote server using Wireshark from my home. I can capture data go out through the Internet, such as when I use this command line `mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t topic -m "Hello"`, I can see the packets in Wireshark. But, When I publish data in localhost, such as using this command `mosquitto_pub -d -h localhost -t hello/world -m "75"` I can't see any packets in Wireshark. I want to make a client/server in the same remote server.

I use this command to open Wireshark:

```
sudo ssh user@x.x.x.x tcpdump -U -s0 -w - | wireshark -k -i -
```

I know only a basic thing in Wireshark, so please how I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the interface that [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) should capture on.  Try adding the `-i lo` option, as in:

```
sudo ssh user@x.x.x.x tcpdump -i lo -U -s0 -w - | wireshark -k -i -
```